# Scailing for MySQL Queries (Straight_Join vs Inner Join)

Tags: mysql

When I make queries across my database - I'm having issues with scaling where if a user has 10k friends - the same query I use for users with 2k friends doesn't scale up, meaning it takes a very long time to process.

The typical situation is that when a user's friend count reaches a certain threshold, I am having to end up using STRAIGHT_JOIN to pull the query, however I need to write conditional statement to first see how many friend and then go from there. The more data, the slower the query to gets.

Is there a better way to scale up your queries via MySQL so they work at the same rate no matter how much data is being generated or am I living in a fantasy world?

EDIT: Query listed below:

```
SELECT photos.photo_id, count(distinct photo_views.ip_address) as total_count
FROM photos
INNER JOIN friends on friends.friend_id = photos.user_id
INNER JOIN photo_views on photos.photo_id = photo_views.photo_id
WHERE friends.user_id = 1 and friends.approved = 1 
and photos.created_at >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
GROUP by photos.photo_id
ORDER by total_count desc
```

Indexes on photos are:

```
[user_id, created_at, photo_id], [user_id], [photo_id] - PRIMARY
```

Indexes on friends are:

```
[user_id, approved], [friend_id], [user_id, friend_id] - PRIMARY
```

Index on photo_views are:

```
[photo_id] - PRIMARY
```

Comment: STRAIGHT_JOIN just helps when you KNOW the proper relation of tables and don't want the engine to think for you.  If you can post the query you are trying to run, there might be other options, such as better indexes, or when/where to adjust WHERE clauses, etc.

Comment: I just added the query above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start with your Friends FIRST as your qualifier so it doesn't try to look at the Photos as the basis which would cover everyone...  Since you are doing an (Inner) join, I would go with the straight_join such as:

```
SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN
      P.Photo_ID, COUNT( distinct PV.IP_Address ) as Total_Count
   FROM
      Friends F
         JOIN Photos P
            ON F.Friend_ID = P.User_ID
            AND P.Created_At >= date_Sub( now(), Interval 30 day )
            JOIN Photo_Views PV
               ON P.Photo_ID = PV.Photo_ID
   WHERE
          F.User_ID = 1
      AND F.Approved = 1
   GROUP BY 
      P.Photo_ID
   ORDER BY
      total_Count DESC
```

This way, you are starting ONLY with those friends for the one user who are approved.  From that, join to the photos of the friends AND the date is qualified... from that, get how many hits per the views table

Comment: This looks really good and is start to pan out in query tests. Users with low and medium counts - the script works perfectly. However - once you start getting into the 15k friends, the query takes around 5 seconds to process. Any ideas?

Comment: @gregavola, add index to your photo_views by (photo_id, ip_address).  That is probably killing your count distinct...

Comment: I tried this and it's still takes around 4-5 seconds to complete for users with 15k+ friends. It's using all the correct indexes (user_id, is_approved) friends, (user_id) - photos, (user_id, ip_address) on photo_views. Very strange...

Comment: @gregavola, if its that important, and you are only looking at a 30-day cycle, you might consider creating a separate aggregate table that is explicitly on photo ID and distinct IP address counts and have it automatically kick-off at the beginning of each day, then query from that.

Comment: So dump all the photo_id and distinct ip_address in the last 30 days in a table on a daily basis and then query from that instead of photo_view?

Comment: @gregavola, yup... then you don't have to worry about count distinct, you can just do a direct JOIN on a single index on the table for Photo_ID and have your answer.

Comment: it's strange though - because even if I take off the "distinct" and just count ip_address, it's still slow. This is because ip_address is a varchar?

Comment: @gregavola, what is the size of your ip_address.  ipV4 format would only be 15 char max.  If you have it as something like 100, or more, that COULD be a basis of plowing through.  Change to just COUNT(*) instead of COUNT( ip_Address ) so it just has to qualify it FOUND a record, not what the content IS.

Comment: that lowered from 5 seconds to 1.2 seconds with the (*). It's current set to VARCHAR255 in case of ipV6 for the future. I guess I can work with that. Thanks for all your help - really helping out!

Comment: If you interesting in trying to solve another one - here is another one I am having trouble with: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9890280/mysql-optimization-for-social-friends-graph-group-by-friends