# MySQL Optimization for Social Friends Graph (Group By Friends)

Tags: mysql, optimization

I'm having a bit of an issue with a query and scaling that query for perfomance with users with high amount of friends. The goal of query is grab the top "activities' performed by your friends in the last 30 days. Here is my query:

```
SELECT a.activity_id, b.activity_name, count(a.activity_id) as total_count
FROM friends as f
INNER JOIN activities as a on (a.user_id = f.friend_id 
and a.created_at >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
INNER JOIN activity as b on a.activity_id = b.activity_id
WHERE f.user_id = 1 and f.is_approved = 1
GROUP by a.activity_id
ORDER by total_count DESC
LIMIT 5
```

This query takes like 25 seconds to run for all users no matter how big or small their friends graph is. Indexes are below:

```
Table: activities
PRIMARY: [act_id] Other: [activity_id, user_id], [user_id, created_at], [created_at]

Table: friends
PRIMARY: [user_id, friend_id] Other: [user_id, is_approved], [friend_id]

Table: activity:
PRIMARY: [activity_id]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE: Here is the explain

```
id  select_type     table   key             key_len         ref             rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE   F  ref     friend_lookup   5   const,const     795     Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE A    ref     user_id         4   F.friend_id     58      Using where
1   SIMPLE    B     eq_ref  PRIMARY         4   P.activty_id    1       Using where
```

Comment: Maybe perform an EXPLAIN [Query] so we can see what the query planner is doing?

Comment: Plz add the explain result to get, how the engine is fetching the data

Comment: I've added the explain above. Not a lot of rows to me - but takes over 25 seconds to query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Robin is correct on the date field.  If you are using a function, it will have to compute that for however many entries its scanning against.  The way I have it below uses MySQL variables.  I calculate it ONCE into an @StartDate and use THAT value for the join clause.

The only additional thing I changed was adding the "STRAIGHT_JOIN" clause.  On many instances, I've found that it has helped myself and others to optimize the query.  It prevents MySQL from trying to interpret the query in another way by possibly looking at the Activity table first since its a smaller file and then back-linking from that one.  "STRAIGHT_JOIN" tells the optimizer to do it in the order you've listed.

```
SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN
      a.activity_id, 
      b.activity_name, 
      count(a.activity_id) as total_count
   FROM 
      ( select @StartDate := date_Sub( now(), interval 30 day ) sqlvars,
      friends as f
         INNER JOIN activities as a 
            on a.user_id = f.friend_id 
           and a.created_at >= @StartDate
         INNER JOIN activity as b 
            on a.activity_id = b.activity_id
   WHERE 
          f.user_id = 1 
      and f.is_approved = 1
   GROUP by 
      a.activity_id
   ORDER by 
      total_count DESC
   LIMIT 5
```

**Per feedback**

That being the case, and having this "rolling 30 days ago" cycle, I would then resort to a nightly table creation that is nothing but a creation by user ID, activity and count and query from that instead...

```
create table DailyRollupActivity
select a.user_id,
       a.activity_id,
       count(*) total_count
   from
      ( select @StartDate := date_Sub( now(), interval 30 day ) sqlvars,
      Activities a
   where
      a.created_at >= @StartDate
   group by
      a.User_ID,
      a.Activity_ID
```

Ensure you have an index on this daily aggregate table by the ( user ID and total count ) then query directly to this based on the friend ID ordered by total_count descending and limit 5.  Small price to pay to have a nightly trigger / event / script to be run to create this ONCE.  How critical is it to see activity for the current date too.  Is the activity that drastic that one day activity would skew what you otherwise want to present to the user?

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I still have problems when the user account is large (has tons of friends). It runs pretty long for users with 800+ friends, quick for the smaller guys. I guess if I can't get query to run in under 2 secs - is there way to denomalize the data properly to get this to run fast? I fear this a scaling issue.

Comment: @gregavola, see revised answer.

Comment: Current date is not critical. My fear is that the activity for the last 30 day will grow significantly, right now we are talking about a nightly job with 600k rows but tomorrow could be 1mm. Is this solution scalable? I just ran the query above - and it took 15 seconds to return values.

Comment: @gregavola, I don't know how / when that may be less receptive, maybe done on a DAILY basis and just store the total on a per friend per activity.  15 seconds at the end of a night in off-time,  Even if you ran it once every hour, you are looking at such as small fraction of time.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this is a time to denormalize a bit.

If you're only storing one degree of separation, this is pretty easy.  Log the "friend activity" for each of the friends at the time the activity takes place.  It will distribute the load to the request of the person performing the activity.

Keep this in mind--after an activity takes place, there's no way for it to "un-take place" (though you might delete record of it from a feed).  This allows you to take a more transactional, logging approach for the sake of performance.

Comment: So your saying that if a user has 15,000 friends, I need to make an insert to the DB 15,000 times for each friend? That doesn't appear to me as optimization - however I could be wrong?

Comment: For an activity log in a graph... well, yeah.  That would scale far better than joins.  And, real-world scenario, how many of your users have 15K friends?  You're both prematurely optimizing, and post-maturely optimizing; pick one ;)

Comment: Additionally, don't be scared by a table filling up.  MySQL is pretty good about handling that.  You can partition it to optimize for the more commonly accessed data (i.e. activity in the past week is going to be read far more than two years ago).

Comment: So you would insert into the row as user_id, friend_id, act_id, and created_at for every item in the activities table. Then I would query this table and join with other tables to get more detailed results?

Comment: Exactly. This log table would do the heavy lifting for you.  One obvious disadvantage is that it won't automatically apply changes in "friendship" retroactively (i.e. if a user adds a new friend, he/she won't see the friend's previous activity unless you insert new records into this table)

Answer (score 0):

Start of by trying to change the query to this:

```
$str_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('today -30 Days'));

SELECT a.activity_id, b.activity_name, count(a.activity_id) as total_count
FROM (  SELECT friend_id
        FROM friends
        WHERE user_id = 1 and is_approved = 1) as f
INNER JOIN (    SELECT user_id, activity_id
                FROM activities
                WHERE created_at >= {$str_date}) as a
on a.user_id = f.friend_id 
INNER JOIN activity as b on a.activity_id = b.activity_id
GROUP by a.activity_id
ORDER by total_count DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Basicly it filters user_id and is_approved before joining the other tables. And It's better to generate that date in php (or whatever language) and use that value in MySQL then to let MySQL calculate the exact same thing (maybe thousands of times).